# To prove $\Bbb Q_p$ is not connected

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I would like to prove $\Bbb Q_p$ is not connected.

My try : Firstly,$\Bbb Z_p$ is not connected because $\Bbb Z_p＝p\Bbb Z_p∪(\Bbb Z_p   - p\Bbb Z_p)$ and both $p\Bbb Z_p$ and   $(\Bbb Z_p   - p\Bbb Z_p)$ are clopen. So, $\Bbb Z_p$ is not connected.

But I don't know any clopen sets of $\Bbb Q_p$. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hint: show $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is compact and open.

Comment: What values can $|x|_p$ take for $x\in\Bbb Q_p$?

Comment: Is it difficult to give an example of clopen subspace of Qp ?

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen  : I think the values can take {p^a｜a∈Z｝∪ ｛0｝.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Hint:*  In any ultrametric space (such as $\mathbb Q_p$), any closed ball is also an open set.  Easy proof from the ultrametric inequality
$d(x,z) \le \max\{d(x,y), d(y,z)\}$.

Not only is it not connected.  It is ["totally disconnected"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_disconnected_space).

Comment: Is closed ball ( you mean {x∈Zp｜｜x｜p≦d｝? ) always closed with respect to p adic topology ? And, is it difficult to give an example of clopen subspace of Qp directly?

Comment: The unit ball in $\mathbb Q_p$  is an easy to give example of a clopen subspace.

Comment: I believe unit ball in Qp is just Zp, then, Qp＝Zp ∪ (Qp-Zp) is an example of decomposition of Qp into two proper closed subset?

Comment: Why not prove it yourself?

Comment: Thank you, I will drop here my proof later. If you are ok, I'm happy if you could check and correct my proof.